# Need Excel sheet Formula

Tags: excel, project-management, formula, excel-formula, time-tracking

Guys I've a weekly Plan for some Projects like as follows. It's Created in Excel-sheet

[image: My Plan]

I need a  Excel formula to get a Reports like as Follows

- Total time assigned for a particular Owner out of 7 days
- Total Open Status tasks of a particular Owner

How to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `SUMIF`?

Comment: @assylias Actually, I don't know how to do this. I'm new to this Excel data manipulation

Comment: Press F1 to access Help. It's a great place to start.

Comment: See for example: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx

Comment: @assylias I tried something like this **=SUMIF(E:E,"=Shree",H:H)** to get the Sum of Time of a **Shree**, But It's returning 0, It suppose to return 2

Comment: it is the way round: `=SUMIF(H:H,"Shree",E:E)`

Comment: @assylias The one that working for me is =SUMIF(H:H,"*Shree",E:E)

Comment: @assylias: How to check multiple conditions here? like `SUM of the TIME where Owner is SHREE and A2="Month 5 - Week 2"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[excel]+multiple+sum+conditions

Comment: @assylias I Tried something like this, But not working for second condition `=SUM(FILTER(E:E,H:H="Shree",A2="Month 5 - Week 2"))`

Comment: @ShreekumarS I suggest you ask a separate question. Also it would great to accept one of the answers as they both seem to solve your initial issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not comfortable with Pivot Tables... I recreated the Excel sheet that you took a picture of and created the report you wanted. Enjoy!

[image]

That same table, but looking at the formulas:

[image]

The total time formula I gave you simply gives you the total time, without a qualifier for the "within 7 days". I wasn't quite sure what you meant by that. How would you determine the within 7 days? By just adding all of the time on line items where the Start Date is within a 7 day period? If so, I can show you how to do that formula as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use Pivot tables. For subtotals per week create one additional column in the base data using the =WEEKNUM() function.